# rsyslog template date/time format with seconds

Tags: server, log, logging, rsyslog

My current template configuration of rsyslog looks like this:

**/etc/rsyslog.d/00-samba-audit.conf**

```
template(name="sambalog" type="string"
 string="%$year%-%$month%-%$day% %$hour%:%$minute% %HOSTNAME% %app-name% %msg%\n")

if $programname == 'smbd_audit' then /var/log/samba/log.audit;sambalog
```

Sadly for no reason there isn't a variable for the seconds.

**Question:** How can I make the date/time format to next?

> 2018-08-09 20:12:58

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variables `$year`, `$day`, ... `$minute` refer to the *current* time. You rather want the timestamp when the event was *generated* or *reported* (see [here](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/properties.html) for the difference). The properties `timegenerated` and `timereported` (==`timestamp`) allow for further processing (i.e. you can pick certain fields from these properties). You cannot pick the seconds from the *current* time but only from the two timestamps mentioned above. So:

```
template(name="sambalog" type="string"
    string="%timereported:::date-year%-%timereported:::date-month%-%timereported:::date-day% %timereported:::date-hour%:%timereported:::date-minute%:%timereported:::date-second% %HOSTNAME% %app-name% %msg%\n")
```

Whoa, this is a very long line and instead of defining the template as a *string* you can also define it as a *list*. The behaviour is the same, just the definition is different and allows for linebrakes and comments in-between. Maybe that improves readability:

```
template(name="sambalog_list" type="list") {
    property(name="timereported" dateFormat="year")
    constant(value="-")
    property(name="timereported" dateFormat="month")
    constant(value="-")
    property(name="timereported" dateFormat="day")
    constant(value=" ")
    property(name="timereported" dateFormat="hour")
    constant(value=":")
    property(name="timereported" dateFormat="minute")
    constant(value=":")
    property(name="timereported" dateFormat="second")
    constant(value=" ")
    property(name="hostname")
    constant(value=" ")
    property(name="app-name")
    property(name="msg" spifno1stsp="on" ) # add space if $msg doesn't start with one
    property(name="msg" droplastlf="on" )  # remove trailing \n from $msg if there is one   
    constant(value="\n")
}

if $programname == 'smbd_audit' then /var/log/so-test.log;sambalog_list
```

When I put the above into `/etc/rsyslog.d/so.conf` and then `systemctl restart syslog.service` and eventually issue

```
logger -t smbd_audit "Hello, $RANDOM"
```

then the file `/var/log/so-test.log` contains:

```
2018-10-12 22:14:12 myhost smbd_audit Hello, 15793
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [the rsyslog docs](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/templates.html):

> The text between percent signs (‘%’) is interpreted by the rsyslog
>   property replacer.

and the [property replacer docs](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/property_replacer.html) say:

> **date-second**
>
> just the second part (2-digit) of a timestamp

So you should be able to put in `%second%` or `%date-second%` into your template to list the seconds.

Comment: No luck: "invalid property 'second' [v8.32.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2207 ]"

Comment: I presume you tried "date-second"?

Answer (score 0):

I did this with

```
%timegenerated:::date-pgsql%
```

Result looks like `2019-09-05 12:22:46`.